# vee-validate 3.X - validate all forms - function

Tags: forms, validation, vue.js, nuxt.js, vee-validate

I used vee-validate with their previous version 2.X and I checked all forms validations with one function.
I triggered my function on the submit button and if all forms are valid I allowed the submission.
It looked something like this:

```js
submit: function() {
  this.$validator.validateAll().then(result => {
    if (result) {
      // submit the form
    } else {
      return
    }
  })
},
```

Now with the new version 3.X a lot of things are changed. I looked in the docs but I could not find any example how can I check the validation of all forms.
Does anyone have some function to share or a way how to do this good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can wrap a `ValidationObserver` around many forms, and then trigger it using a `validate()` call:

Refer:
https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/validation-observer.html#examples